# Objects storing data and objects storing smart pointers to data

Tags: c++

Let's say I want to organise fleets in my galactic empire.

```cpp
class Fleet
{
    string m_commander;
    int m_totalShips;
}


class GalacticEmpire
{
    string m_coolName;
    string m_edgyTitleOfTheRuler;
    /*Problem line number1*/
}
```

`GalacticEmpire` is an object that will own and control everything that is solely of my empire - it will store all the bytes of its data.

But my `GalacticEmpire` does not exist in void (I mean technically it does), there are `StarSystem`s it controls.

```
class StarSystem
{
    string m_name;
    color m_starColor;
    /*Problem line number2*/
}
```

Now `StarSystem` is not supposed to store any raw data - it only has to be able to point to `Fleet`s that station within its bounds.

And now the question.

How `GalacticEmpire` should store `Fleet`s so that it can access them and destroy them (entirely from program) and simultaneosly how `StarSystem` should be able to point to `Fleets`s so that it can iterate over them?
In the other words, how should `Problem line number1` and `Problem line number2` look like?

Option #1:

Problem line number1 = `vector<Fleet> m_fleets`

Problem line number2 = `vector<shared_ptr<Fleet>> m_fleets`

Option #2:

Problem line number1 = Problem line number2 
= `vector<shared_ptr<Fleet>> m_fleets`

Comment: Why not have the fleets point to the star systems they are in?  Star systems really shouldn't ever go away so it makes managing this easier.

Comment: @NathanOliver Let's say a `Fleet` arrives at a certain `StarSystem`. Now if there's an enemy `Fleet` in the same `StarSystem`, a battle should break out. Without `StarSystem`s storing `Fleet`s within their bounds, I will have to iterate through all `Fleet`s to find whether a battle is happening.

Comment: Try to think about the problem in terms of "ownership" and "access need". Who owns a fleet - GalacticEmpire or StarSystem? Who needs to access whom? Should fleet know in which StarSystem it is or should StarSystem know what fleets are in it?

Comment: Sure, it is little more work but how many fleets are we talking about?  If the users are controlling the fleets I can tell you from experience with stellaris that 20 fleets can be tough to manage.

Comment: Can you (maybe) have a pointer to `StarSystem` in `GalacticEmpire` (or vice-versa)? Then just store `Fleet` in one and have the other fetch it from there.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the `GalacticEmpire` will outlive any `StarSystem` objects that access its `Fleet`s?  Your question will be answerable once you clear that up.

Comment: @Spencer Yes - `GalacticEmpire` can be deleted only after each of its `Fleet`s were previously destroyed which also means taking them out of all `StarSystem`s.

Comment: What would be the best depends on the operations you need to be able to perform and the performance requirements.One flexible approach however would be to have a FleetPool that holds all fleets (in a vector),both GalacticEmpire and StarSystem store encapsulated pointers to the fleets, the fleet stores encapsulated pointer to GalacticEmpire and StarSystem, and everything is kept linked by properly setting up constructors and destructors with help of RAII. It works basically like a bunch of small linked lists. It's a complex solution with some tradeoffs, but it allows O(1) insertion and removal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems to be an interesting exercise in object design. Let's try something out naively.

```
class GalacticEmpire
{
    std::string m_coolName;
    std::string m_edgyTitleOfTheRuler;
    std::vector<Fleet> fleets;
};
```

That seems right - Empire owns it's own fleets, they are arranged in the container (vector), and we do not need to use any indirection here - vector stores `Fleet` objects.

Now, let's use view pointer in the `StarSystem`:

```
class StarSystem
{
    string m_name;
    color m_starColor;
    std::vector<Fleet*> fleets;
}
```

We will populate `StarSystem::fleets` with addresses from `GalacticEmpire::fleet`, and it seems to work at the first glance.

Unfortunately, this solution is extremely brittle. If `Empire` happens to add new fleets to it's force, it would do this by adding objects to `GalacticEmpire::fleets` vector and will invalidate the addresses to those stored in `StarSystem::fleets`. Not great!

Second attempt:

```
 class GalacticEmpire
 {
    // ...
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Fleet>> fleets;
 };
```

And `StarSystem::fleets` store (non-owning) pointer managed by `unique_ptr`s of `GalacticEmpire::fleets`. This solves us a problem of adding new fleets - even if pushing new elements to the vector ivalidates pointers to `unique_ptr`s, the pointers managed by said ptrs remain valid.

However, this solution has two drawbacks: you loosing performance. Objects which could be stored directly in the vector of fleets are now created dynamically. Accessing those requires indirection, and it all takes a heavy toll on performance.

The other problem is logical - we have solved a problem of adding new fleet, but what if the fleet is removed? We do need to clean-up this fleet from the StarSystem it expected to be!

Let's think for a moment. It is clear that a `StarSystem` can host multiple fleets, but a fleet can only be stationed within a single `StarSystem`. Let's use this information:

```
class Fleet
{
    string m_commander;
    int m_totalShips;
    StarSystem* stationed_system;
};
```

We add the pointer to the StarSystem this fleet is hosted to the fleet itself. Now, when an Empire looses one of it's fleets, we should be able to clear that fleet from the list of fleets stationed in the StarSystem. But, how do we find it? Iteratively in the vector? This is rather slow. Let's do unordered_set instead, so we will be able to find (and remove) a fleet in constant time!

```
class StarSystem
{
    std::unordered_set<Fleet*> fleets;
};
```

Now, the only thing left is to make sure we introduce a certain type of friendship between classes and add some private and public functions which would guarantee that anytime a fleet is removed it is also removed from it's StarSystem. This is left for the reader.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I get the question but you can create an array of `Fleet` if you know beforehand how many fleets

```
class GalacticEmpire
{
    Fleet* fleet = new Fleet [10]; //this is a pointer to the first position of a 10 size Fleet array
    string m_coolName;
    string m_edgyTitleOfTheRuler;
    /*Problem line number1*/
}
```

if I remember correctly, you need to have declared the Fleet class before the Galactic Empire one, if you are working with 1 file.
Also if you don't know the fleet size you can use a linked list instead.

Edit: you will have to release the memory when you are done using it with `delete[] fleet;`